# Is it possible to save file into any collection like hashmap or hashtable?

Tags: java, file, collections, hashmap, hashtable

I just wanted to save a file into hashmap or hashtable or any type of collection.
Like HashMap = {"fileName" : "File Content"}
But i did not find any ways to do that.

Can someone please help me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How big is the file? Is your memory enough for the file content, if it is, you could read the file as `String` or `[]byte` then put it into the Map

Answer (score 0):

you can try `HashMap<String,String>`.
It will be more efficient to store the file locations as value, instead of storing the whole file in hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Assume all your jsons are stored in `src/main/resources` folder, then you can do like this.

1.First write a method to read json file like this :

```
public String readJson(String fileName) throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder responseData = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseData.append(line);
        }
        return responseData.toString();
    }
```

2.Now create a `HashMap<String,String>` , and call above method for each file

```
public void storeFileDataAsMap() {
    Map<String, String> fileMap = new HashMap<>(); 
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("src/main/resources"))) {
            paths
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .forEach(eachFile->{
                    try {
                        String fileName = eachFile.toAbsolutePath().toString();
                        fileMap.put(eachFile.getFileName().toString(), readJson(fileName));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("File not found exception");
                    }
                });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("File not found exception");
        }
    }
```